# Controlling motor with potential on 2 points

Tags: motor

I have 2 nodes where minimum voltage is 2.7v and maximum voltage is 5v. I would like to turn ON a motor when both nodes have 5v and turn off when both nodes have 2.7v.

1. Node1 - 5v & Node2 - 5v      Motor ON
2. Node1 - 5v & Node2 - 2.7v    Motor ON
3. Node1 - 2.7v & point2 - 2.7v  Motor OFF

How can i achieve this??

Comment: Your list of states contradicts your earlier statement. Do you mean the motor should turn on when EITHER point (node?) is at 5V? To solve this problem, you also need to indicate where the change of state should occur.  Can the voltages only be 2.7V (give or take how much?) and 5V, or can they vary continuously between those values? If so, when should the motor turn off? When both voltages fall to 2.7V, 2.8V, 2.9V? If you provide this information a solution is easier.

Comment: There are two states only. The voltage stays constant at 2.7 (give or take .1v) and 5v (give or take .1v). Yes. Your interpretation is right. Motor should be on when both nodes are at 5v and should stay on when one node at 5v and other at 2.7v and should be off when both nodes are at 2.7v.

Comment: If you are saying that when the motor is off, both inputs must be at 5V to turn it on, then the OR gate in my solution below will not work and the solution becomes a little more complex. I understood you to mean that either must be at 5V.

Comment: Is there anyway i can share you my simulation file?? Can you help me sort this out?

Comment: Edit your question with the relevant information from the simulation, or with a screenshot of it.

Comment: Thanks for the simulation schematic. I'll stay on topic and won't study the rest of the circuit. D1 and D2 can be signal diodes. You must design the resistors, 10k everywhere won't cut it. Again, R1 and R2 are a divider setting the switching threshold. R3 is typically much larger, you can find standard comparator hysteresis equations with google. 10k for the MOSFET gate resistor is not helpful either, as a initial stab throw in 100R.

Comment: Thanks.. I will google and design them.. Can you have a look at the tx and rx session? In the tx session we can see some switches.  In the hardware implementation i will replace them with float sensors. What i am trying to achieve is make the motor on when all of the switches are open ( that means tank is empty). As the tank filled with water motor should me off and as the water is utilised motor should be made on when all the switches are open and this should repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comparator, along these lines:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjxKad.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The noninverting input sees the higher of your sample points minus a diode drop. It will see about 4.3V if either In1 or In2 is 5V, or about 2V if both are 2.7V.

The divider formed by R1 and R2 sets your threshold for turning the motor on. You should design this divider with the values in the previous paragraph in mind.

R3 adds some hysteresis for stability. You can google information about calculating this value based on your required noise margin.

R5 is a pullup needed if you use a comparator with an open drain output.

M1 just represents a generic drive for your motor, since you didn't say what you were using.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Let me simulate this circuit. I am using a dc motor.